# Can Dart support abstract type member use cases?

Tags: scala, dart, abstract-type, type-members

Scala has a concept of abstract type members that, among other things, allow essentially defining legal mappings between types without having to repeatedly specify potentially invalid combinations of type parameters.
For example, when modeling domain entities abstractly, where an entity has a specific id type, we can write something like

```scala
trait Entity {
    type Id
}
```

And then use this trait as

```scala
trait UserId
class User extends Entity {
    override type Id = UserId
}
trait ProductId
class Product extends Entity {
    override type Id = ProductId
}
// etc
```

This way, when we want to operate on `Entity`s generically, we can just refer to `[X <: Entity]`, as opposed to also have to provide an `Id` (ie we don't have to specify something like `[Id, X <: Entity[Id]]`). This is both more ergonomic and ensures correctness when referring to an `Entity` and it's `Id` type.

Is it possible to support anything along these lines with Dart?

EDIT:
I have an idea for a workable alternative, but not sure if it's possible at all. Dart allows you to access the type of a generic parameter as a value. Is it possible to get type parameters of type, that could allow something like

```dart
abstract class Entity<Id> { ... }

class Repo<E extends Entity> {
    final t = E; // here we can refer to the type E as a value

    // can you then use `t` to access type parameters it may have?
    // something like `t.typeParameters`... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only kind of type parameterization that Dart allows is generics.

That means doing something like:

```dart
abstract interface class Entity<Id> {}
class User implements Entity<UserId> {}
class Product implements Entity<ProductId> {}
```

That doesn't allow you to use the type for anything. The easiest way to get that is something like:

```dart
abstract base class Entity<Id> {
  R runWithId<R>(R Function<X>(Entity<X> self) action) => action<Id>(this);
}
final class User extends Entity<UserId> {}
final class Product extends Entity<ProductId> {}
```

Then you can do something like:

```dart
  Entity<Object?> entity = someEntity;
  entity.runWithId(<Id>(idEntity) {
    // Can use `Id` as  a type and `idEntity` of type `Entity<Id>`.
    List<Id> entities = [idEntity]; // fx.
  });
```

That gives you access to the *actual* type argument of the `Entity` instance, not just the static type. There is currently no way to access that from the outside, it requires cooperation from the class itself.